# Use UI-Bootstrap Modal with Angular-Fullstack and ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-fullstack

I would like to use the [ui-bootsrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) with the [AngularJS Fullstack Generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) & ES6, but it doesn't work. 
I would like to choose a Project, click "Edit" and edit the Project in a large Modal. But I don't get the modal to open.

In the Console, I get this error Message:

```
"Error: $modal is not defined"
```

**My Project Controller looks like this:**

```
'use strict';

(function() {

  class ProjectCtrl {

    constructor(Project, $modal, $log) {
      this.project = Project;
      this.projects = [];
      this.getAllProjects(Project);
      this.$modal = $modal;
      this.log = $log;
    }

    // Open a modal window to Update a single Project
    modalUpdate(size, selectedProject) {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/project/project-edit.modal.html',
        controller: function ($scope, modalInstance, aProject) {
          $scope.project = aProject;
        },
        size: size,
        resolve: {
          aProject: function () {
            return selectedProject;
          }
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        this.selected = selectedItem;
      }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });
    };
  }

angular.module('projectApp')
    .controller('ProjectCtrl', ProjectCtrl);
})();
```

**app.js looks like this:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('projectApp', [
  'projectApp.constants',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap' 
])
  .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

**The Button to open the Modal:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" ng-click="ProjectCtrl.modalUpdate('lg', project)"><span aria-hidden="false"></span> Edit</button>
```

My guess is that in ProjectCtrl, I have somehow to $inject 'Project', '$modal' & '$log', but I don't know how and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the Modal problem in another way, cause it seems that UI Bootstrap doesn't work in ES6. At least not now.

I used the Modal Service [here](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/tree/master/templates/app/client/components/modal(uibootstrap)) for Angular-Fullstack.

Here is a simple example with a delete Modal:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

class AdminController {
  constructor(User, Modal) {
    // Use the User $resource to fetch all users
    this.users = User.query();
    this.modal = Modal;
  }

  delete(user) {
    var deleteConfirmationModal = this.modal.confirm.delete((user) => {
        user.$remove();
        this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);
    });

    deleteConfirmationModal(user.name, user);
  }
}

angular.module('sampleApp.admin')
  .controller('AdminController', AdminController);

})();
```

This is how the Modal looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ui-bootstrap are you using ?

The syntax is different depending on which version you're using.

Assuming you're using **v0.13.4 or older** and without ES6, here the solution :

NOTE : 
If you're using **more recent version than v0.13.4** then replace `$modal` by `$uibModal` and `$modalInstance` by `$uibModalInstance` and it should work too.

---

First, what you need to do is write in the command line :

```
yo angular-fullstack:controller MyModalName
```

then in **myModalName.controller.js** put this :

```
.controller('MyModalNameCtrl', function ($scope,$modal) {

$scope.openModal = function () {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'testmodal',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',

  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function () {}, function () {
    console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
};
```

});

Then still in **myModalName.controller.js** put below :

```
//change theNameOfYourApp to your corresponding app name !
angular.module('theNameOfYourApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close(); 
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Then last step, **in your .html page** where you want to display the modal, put :

```
<!--Modal Template-->
<div ng-controller="MyModalNameCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="testmodal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Hello :</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>hey, this is the body </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>

      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel()</button>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my ui-bootstrap to the latest version yesterday.

Isn't there any other way to solve the problem in my already existing "ProjectCtrl"? I am using this Controller for the CRUD operations and I wanted to use the Modal to update values of the project. 
But I wrote the ProjectCtrl in ES6 and don't know how to implement the modal also in ES6.

Comment: I don't have good knowledge about ES6, so I can't really help you in this case :/ Maybe, take back my above example, and translate what I wrote into ES6, It should not be too difficult I guess.